# Python scatter plot, axis scale

Tags: python, scatter-plot

I'm doing a scatter plot for the vector y that contains 125 entries this way:

```
x = np.arange(1,126)

plt.scatter(x,y)
```

The case is I don't want the x-axis to have a number for each point in the diagram, I want to group the points in sets of 5, that is the number 1 in the x-axis correspond to the first 5 points, number 2 correspond to the next 5 and so on... so x should be:

```
x = np.arrage(1,26)
```

But I don't know if that is going to work.

Please help.
Thanks you very much.

Comment: Try this https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/04.10-customizing-ticks.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Not sure if it is what you are after. But hopefully a start.

```
ticks = []; j = 1
for i in x:
    if i % 5 == 0:
        ticks.append(j)
        j += 1
    else:
        ticks.append('')
plt.xticks(x, ticks)
```